# How to get MediaType (screen, handheld, etc) from ManagedBean when page is loading?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have a JSF page in my app with a table using PrimeFaces. This table has an ajax method that should execute when a specific event is fired:
If the client browser is from a mobile device (handheld), then the event that should fire the ajax request must be `onSelect`, otherwise (for desktops) the event must be `onDblselect` (double click).

This is the ajax inside the table:

```
<p:ajax event="rowDblselect" listener="#{productController.productSelect}" update=":mainForm" />
```

As you can see, the event right now is fixed. I know i can get the device type using the command `window.matchMedia('screen and (max-width: 765px)').matches` in javascript, which returns `true` or `false`. But how can i bind it to the event, since the "event" attribute of the ajax tag does not accept javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating two ajax listeners, one for each event, and the one not fit for the specific device is cancelled trough javascript on the onStart method, like this:

```
<p:ajax event="rowDblselect" onstart="return !isMobileDevice();" listener="#{productController.productSelect}" update=":mainForm" />
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" onstart="return isMobileDevice();" listener="#{productController.productSelect}" update=":mainForm" />
```

isMobileDevice is a simple JS function:

```
function isMobileDevice() {
    return window.matchMedia("screen and (max-width: 765px)").matches;
}
```

Comment: What PF version? If I remember correctly, up to recent PF versions, returning false in the onstart did not prevent the listener to be called